# How do I make this code shorter and more automated

Tags: python

```
amount = eval(input("Enter the amount of money: "))

fiveHundred = amount // 500
amount = amount % 500
twoHundred = amount // 200
amount = amount % 200
oneHundred = amount // 100
amount = amount % 100
fifty = amount // 50
amount = amount % 50
twenty = amount // 20
amount = amount % 20
ten = amount // 10
amount = amount % 10
five = amount // 5
amount = amount % 5
two = amount // 2
amount = amount % 2
one = amount // 1
amount = amount % 1
print(f"You have \n"
      f"\t500 riyal: {fiveHundred} \n"
      f"\t200 riyal: {twoHundred} "
      f"\n\t100 riyal: {oneHundred} "
      f"\n\t50 riyal: {fifty} "
      f"\n\t20 riyal: {twenty} "
      f"\n\t10 riyal: {ten} "
      f"\n\t5 riyal: {five} "
      f"\n\t2 riyal: {two} "
      f"\n\t1 riyal: {one}")
```

It worked just fine with any number input but I would like to know if there's a way to reduce lines of code and make it way more professional.

Comment: Look at the `divmod` built-in function.

Comment: This question belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, because your code works, you just want a review of it, which is off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 2):

`divmod` returns both the division result and the remainder, which is what you're doing for each denomination.

Then you can use a loop for your currency denominations instead of having to write them out by yourself.

Finally, never use `eval`, because it allows users to enter arbitrary code (and you can't be sure of the data type returned anyway); if you want to convert a string to an integer, use `int()`.

```
amount = int(input("Enter the amount of money: "))
print("You have")
for denomination in [500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1]:
    amount_den, amount = divmod(amount, denomination)
    print(f"\t{denomination} riyal: {amount_den}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
amount = int(input("Enter the amount of money: "))

denominations = [500,200,100,50,20,10,5,2,1]
output_denom = [0 for i in range(len(denominations))]

for index in range(len(denominations)):
    output_denom[index] = amount//denominations[index]
    amount = amount % denominations[index]

output_str = "You have \n"
for index in range(len(denominations)):
    output_str += f"\t{denominations[index]} riyal: {output_denom[index]} \n" 

print(output_str)
```

Comment: One optimization you can do is use `divmod` function to reduce it to one line in the first for loop.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is almost identical to AKX's answer.

You can collect all the note values in one list, and use a for-loop to run through all the value in order from biggest to smallest, provided they are already in that order. Also I don't really see the need for `eval()` when you can just use `int()`. This, of course, ignores any room for an invalid input like "two hundred" or "45.9" but I'm assuming it's unnecessary for what you have asked.

This should do the trick:

```
amount = int(input("Enter the amount of money: "))
notes = [500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1]
print("You have")
for note in notes:
    num_notes = amount // note
    print("\t{} riyal: {}".format(note, num_notes))
    amount %= note
```